Strange behavior of UDP listening on Windows: how to handle OS errors
When binding and listening for UDP on Windows, an exception is thrown when using socket.send to send data to a port where no service is running. How can I ignore this exception and continue listening for UDP data while still being able to send other data normally? Additionally, there are some strange behaviors accompanying this.
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
  RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 9999)
      .then((RawDatagramSocket socket) {
    socket.broadcastEnabled = true;
    socket.listen(
        (RawSocketEvent event) {
          if (event == RawSocketEvent.read) {
            Datagram? datagram = socket.receive();
            if (datagram != null) {
              String message = utf8.decode(datagram.data);
              print(
                  'Received: $message from ${datagram.address.address}:${datagram.port}');
            }
          }
        },
        onError: (e, s) {
          print('Error: $e');
        },
        cancelOnError: false,
        onDone: () {
          print('Done');
        });
    socket.send(utf8.encode("hello"), InternetAddress('127.0.0.1'), 9999);
    socket.send(utf8.encode("hello"), InternetAddress('127.0.0.1'), 9999);
    socket.send(utf8.encode("hello"), InternetAddress('127.0.0.1'), 12345);
    socket.send(utf8.encode("hello"), InternetAddress('127.0.0.1'), 9999);
  });
}


Execute on my Windows 10 computer.
Received: hello from 127.0.0.1:9999
Received: hello from 127.0.0.1:9999


When sending data to port 12345, the listener stops working, and no errors appear.
But if I comment out the send in the first two lines   "Like this
    // socket.send(utf8.encode("hello"), InternetAddress('127.0.0.1'), 9999);
    // socket.send(utf8.encode("hello"), InternetAddress('127.0.0.1'), 9999);
    socket.send(utf8.encode("hello"), InternetAddress('127.0.0.1'), 12345);
    socket.send(utf8.encode("hello"), InternetAddress('127.0.0.1'), 9999);

Execute on my Windows 10 computer.
C:/Users/ws/Downloads/dartsdk-windows-x64-release/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe --enable-asserts --no-serve-devtools D:\code\android\untitled1\dt1\bin\dt1.dart
Error: SocketException: No service is operating at the destination network endpoint on the remote system
 (OS Error: No service is operating at the destination network endpoint on the remote system。
, errno = 1234), address = 0.0.0.0, port = 9999

In fact, my program needs to send commands to some devices in the local area network to check their status and receive operational reports.
After an exception occurs, it completely stops
I hope to ignore this exception and continue working.
And i found a similar issue, but on python，   https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91227
I have found a way to bypass this problem, but there are still some non intuitive behaviors
Define a send method and rebind the same port within the method. The errors that occur will not cause the monitoring to fail.
errors can still occur in the callback method of listening, even if the listening socket is not used for sending  
int sendPing(RawDatagramSocket socket, String ip) {
  print("scan $ip");
  return send("ping", ip, 2369, socket);
}

void sendPingList(RawDatagramSocket socket, List<String> ip) async{
\\  Do not use listening sockets
  for (var o in ip) {
    var socket1 = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 9999);
    sendPing(socket1, o);
    socket1.close();
  }
}


You already appear to be ignoring it (with cancelOnError being false). Does Done get printed? Does the whole application exit?

hi @RichardHeap Done cannot be printed.I've found a way around the problem, but there's still some unintuitive behavior.The issue has been edited
